# How can I avoid global state when programming with React?

Tags: reactjs, flux

Tons of examples, describing React and Flux uses global variables: global `Dispatcher`, global `Store` and etc. Is there any way to proper inject dependencies to react components? There are some articles on the web describing how to use Dependency Injection component with React, but it based on undocumented weird feature called "Context" [with unknown future](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/580#issuecomment-38202652).

Proper injection, for me, is classic constructor-based injection, without accessing global variables, without accessing static state and other.

It seems that I need to hook into component construction process (place, where `new` called). Can I do that? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do dependency *inversion* with React is to simply pass any necessary dependencies as properties to the components that need them. Context is simply a way to pass the props down through child components, grandchild components, and so on implicitly without listing the prop on every component that may need it.

You'll find a lot of examples of this technique in the wild, and many make use of context and other niceties. [React Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux) is a popular one right now; pass a local variable to a top-level `<Provider>` component as a property, and it wires up the rest for you.

Dependency *injection* is less straightforward, and you'd probably need some kind of proper DI container or a DI library for JavaScript to do this nicely. Components aren't really instantiated, from the user's standpoint, the way other JS objects are, so doing "at instantiation time" injection of dependencies into components isn't how I'd approach the problem.